# UITouch in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying convert my swift 1.2 code to 2.0 I have a function like this:

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let anyTouch =  (touches.first as? UITouch)!
}
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Downcast from 'UITouch?' to 'UITouch' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `let anyTouch = touches.first as! UITouch`. ?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8k3pzs

Comment: Maybe just `let anyTouch = touches.first`

Comment: Oh it worked. Thank you. If you answer this question i'll mark it. But I have one more problem. Do you know how to resolve these? http://prntscr.com/8k3tjh

Comment: Actually you probably want `let anyTouch = touches.first!` you still want to unwrap the optional but you don't need the downcast because the type is specified for the set as being a UITouch

Comment: Thank you. Did you check my second screenshot?

Comment: Are you using the released Xcode 7 ? I saw a comment in another question regarding those errors that it was a bug that was supposed to be fixed

Comment: I put that code into a playground and didn't get those errors

Comment: Do you have an idea for fix this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90565/discussion-between-paulw11-and-okan).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of the Set's contents are specified as being `UITouch` in the function signature so you don't need the downcast.  All you need is to unwrap the optional.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let anyTouch =  touches.first
}
```